# Поставил с нуля англоязычную windows 10 и слетела кодировка

Tags: windows, кодировка, windows-10

Переустановил windows 10, поставил англоязычную версию и после этого и в блокноте, и в некоторых программах, русский текст отображается коряво[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как и где настроить кодировку?

Comment: PowerShell с правами админа: `Set-WinSystemLocale 'ru-RU'; Restart-Computer`.

Comment: Но в таком случае будет ли адекватно работать английская локализация системы?

Comment: По идее должна, но лично я не тестировал. Если не хотите менять системную настройку, то тогда могу предложить ознакомиться с этим [ответом на Super User](http://superuser.com/a/1170441).

Comment: Вам надо чтобы язык интерфейса был на анг ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

работаешь с блокнотом , 
сохраняешь в анси , 
смотришь,  как работают другие программы,  типа нотепад++ или копирование из экселя и вставка в блокнот...

пробуешь сохранять в ютф 8 в блокноте,  и снова проверяешь в нотепад++  и копипаст из экселя вба в блокнот ...

находишь последнее оптимальное для тебя сохранение как ..., адекватно отражающее кириллицу  , потом забываешь про блокнот,  и не пользуешься им больше никогда ...